# Pass also value with the shown item in listbox Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to fill a listbox from the above database query.The Listbox shows correctly the "PLAYER" results as items.I want also to assign a value member for all these items as "ID" from database.How it can be this?

```
   SqlDataAdapter sdaa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PLAYERS.ID, CAST(PLAYERS.NO AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME AS PLAYER FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAMS ON PLAYERS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.ID WHERE (TEAMS.NAME =oly ", con);
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        sdaa.Fill(dta);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["PLAYER"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the `dataTable` to the `listbox.DataSource` and then set the `ValueMemeber`(hidden field) and display member

```
SqlDataAdapter sdaa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PLAYERS.ID, CAST(PLAYERS.NO AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME AS PLAYER FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAMS ON PLAYERS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.ID WHERE (TEAMS.NAME =oly ", con);
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sdaa.Fill(dta);
    listbox3.DataSource=dta;
    listbox3.DisplayMember="PLAYER";
    listbox3.ValueMember="ID";
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want. You want add manually(using the loop) the value memebers? @Apollon